# PyTorch's torch.nn.functional.interpolate behaving strangely

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

I'm having issues with PyTorch's tensor-resizing options. In the following code, `x` is a dataset of 888 64x64 RGB images of pokemon. `xs` is to be a dictionary of the same dataset at different resolutions.

```
def load_data():
    pokemon = []
    for png in os.listdir("pokemon"):
        pokemon.append(imageio.imread("pokemon/" + png))
    pokemon = np.array(pokemon)
    s = pokemon.shape
    pokemon = pokemon.reshape((s[0], s[-1], s[1], s[2]))
    pokemon = (pokemon.astype(np.float32) - 127.5)/127.5
    return(pokemon)
x = load_data()

ss = [2, 1, 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16]
xs = {s : nn.functional.interpolate(torch.from_numpy(x), scale_factor = s, mode='nearest') for s in ss}
```

As expected, the output shapes include all 888 RGB images with new heights and widths.

```
print("Data shape:")
for x in xs.values():
    print(" ", x.shape)

> Data shape:
>  torch.Size([888, 3, 128, 128])
>  torch.Size([888, 3, 64, 64])
>  torch.Size([888, 3, 32, 32])
>  torch.Size([888, 3, 16, 16])
>  torch.Size([888, 3, 8, 8])
>  torch.Size([888, 3, 4, 4])
```

However, the images weren't sensibly resized.

- When **s = 1**, the pokemon are in their ordinary 64x64 format, as expected:

  [image]
- When **s = 2**, the pokemon become Pollocks, overlapping in different colors:

  [image]
- When **s = 1/2**, the pokemon are cut into pieces and rearranged:

  [image]

Is there an alternative PyTorch tool for resizing? I encounter roughly the same problem using `AvgPool2d` and `Upsample` instead. I will be resizing non-image tensors, too, so `PIL` isn't always an option. In any case, using the GPU instead of CPU would be helpful.

Comment: In `torch.from_numpy(x)`, what is `x`? Can you show an example?

Comment: Also, can you change the `dtype` of `torch.from_numpy(x)` to `float32` or something if it is a `int` right now? Does that help?

Comment: ```x``` is a numpy array of shape ```[888, 3, 64, 64]```. Each image has been normalized, so elements are between -1 and 1, and it is of ```dtype float 32```. I'll add the construction of ```x``` to my question.

Comment: Here's a layer of ```x``` anyway:

array([[[ 1. ,  1.        ,  1.        , ...,  1.        ,
          1.        ,  1.        ],
        ...,
        [ 1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        , ...,  1.        ,
          1.        ,  1.        ]]], dtype=float32)

Comment: I believe this may be because I'm confused swapping from Keras-style (B, H, W, C) to PyTorch-style (B, C, H, W). I'll keep working on this.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved my problem. I was unused to transitioning images from `(Batch, Height, Width, Channels)` to `(Batch, Channels, Height, Width)` for `PyTorch`. Replacing the `reshape` lines with `np.moveaxis` fixed the issue. Thanks, everyone, for your help.

Comment: Maybe using `np.transpose` is a better in term of readability as its arguments exactly matches `torch.permute`. Just as a note, all `transforms` in pytorch now support GPU/CPU and tensor and PIL data. If you really need large toolset of image transformations, you can use `kornia` which is differentiable too!

Comment: Oh, thank you for recommending kornia! Its colorspace-conversion is another tool I happened to need.